# How to compare value of variable against #define

Tags: objective-c, c, syntax

I have made the following #defines

```
#define GOLD 1;
#define SILVER 2;
```

later in my program I set up some variables

```
int source, target;
```

They are then set to the values:

```
source = GOLD;
target = SILVER;
```

I now want to compare in an if statement:

```
if(source == GOLD) {...}
```

But the compiler complains Expected ')' before ';' token.  If I change the line to

```
if(source == 1) {...}
```

There is no problem with the compiler or the behavior.  How do I reference the #define in the if statement to make myself clear to the compiler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you have an errant `;` after the `#define GOLD 1` and `#define SILVER 2`. Remove them, your problem will go away.

Comment: As well as after `#define SILVER`.